# How is $(n+1)(n+2) / 2$ derived in this induction step?

Tags: induction

I'm attempting to understand in how to get from step1 to step2 :

Step 1. $1+2+\cdots+n = n(n+1)/2 $

Step 2. Need to show $1+2+\cdots+(n+1)= (n+1)(n+2) / 2$

How is $(n+1)(n+2) / 2$ derived from replacing $n$ in step 1 with $(n+1)$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $(n+1)(n+2)/2$, or the right-hand side, is derived by using the *induction hypothesis*.

You assume 
$$
1+2+\cdots+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}
$$
is true for some $k\geq 1$. You need to use this assumption, called the induction hypothesis, in your derivation.

For example, you have the following
\begin{align}
1+2+\cdots+k+(k+1) &= \underbrace{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}_{1+2+\cdots+k=\frac{k(k+1)}{2}\;\text{(induction hypothesis)}}+(k+1)\\[1em]
  &= \frac{k(k+1)+2(k+1)}{2}\qquad\text{(common denominator)}\\[1em]
  &= \frac{(k+1)(k+2)}{2}\qquad\text{(desired expression)}
\end{align}
Do you see how this worked?

Comment: thank you, can you elaborate on how you derived the desired expression from the common denominator ?

Comment: @blue-sky I'm not entirely sure what your question is--if you meant how I got from the expression where there is a common denominator to the desired expression, then this is not too hard to figure out if you reason as follows: $\color{blue}{k}(\color{red}{k+1})+\color{blue}{2}(\color{red}{k+1})=(\color{blue}{k+2})(\color{red}{k+1})$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: yes that makes sense now, is there a name or formula for factoring "k(k+1)+2(k+1)=(k+2)(k+1)" as it does appear familiar ?

Comment: @blue-sky It's simply *combining* like terms. For example, if you had $k(k+1)+2(k+1)+r(k+1)$, then you can now see why this would be equivalent to $(k+2+r)(k+1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
{\huge(} 1+2+3+\cdots+n {\huge)} + (n+1) = \text{something}+(n+1).
$$
The "something" comes from the induction hypothesis, i.e. from the case involving $n$ rather than $n+1$.